# Float section bar like telegram in recyclerview or listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I need float section bar in the left side of my `RecyclerView` to show date of items in that section **like telegram contact activity**. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: [https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) May be this is what You want.

Comment: there is no version number for this project i cant sync gradle @Krishna

Comment: compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.6.0'  or 2.1.5 check this version

Comment: [https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders/releases](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders/releases) check here multiple versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.tonicartos:superslim:0.4.13'
}
```

[image]